# How to keep a value constant until a certain condition is met

Tags: r

i am currently trying to keep a certain value constant until a condition is met. Specifically, each month I select a stock under a certain selection model ("buy" column), then i keep this stock for one quarter. The portfolios consequently overlap.  Now, i want to apply a "Hold-to-maturity" scheme that keeps e.g. the price constant until it is sold again. See below for an example. The column "htm_prc" is supposed to keep the share price constant from the first month it was bought until it is sold again.

| Date | prc | buy | portfolio | htm_prc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jan 2001 | 34 | 1 | 1 | 34 |
| Feb 2001 | 35 | 1 | 1 | 34 |
| Mar 2001 | 38 | 0 | 1 | 34 |
| Apr 2001 | 24 | 0 | 1 | 24 |
| May 2001 | 22 | 0 | 0 | #NA |
| Jun 2001 | 18 | 1 | 1 | 18 |
| Jul 2001 | 30 | 0 | 1 | 18 |
| Aug 2001 | 32 | 0 | 1 | 32 |
| Sep 2001 | 38 | 0 | 0 | #NA |

Here is the sample data:

```
htm <- data.frame (Date  = c("Jan 2001", "Feb 2001", "Mar 2001", "Apr 2001", "May 2001", "Jun 2001", "Jul 2001", "Aug 2001", "Aug 2001"),
              prc = c(34, 35, 38, 24, 22, 18, 30, 32, 38),
              buy = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0),
              portfolio = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0),
              htm_prc = c(34, 34, 34, 24, NA, 18, 18, 32, NA)
)
```

Maybe some of you have a solution for me!

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If I understand correctly, Feb 2001 has `buy == 1` but a run of 2 months with the same `hmt_prc` when it was supposed to be a run of 3 months? Are the cases like this that must be changed?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, so these prices are beginning of month data, so in my understanding you hold the stock in Feb 2001, Mar 2001 and Apr 2001.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function below takes a vector of `htm_prc` and a vector of `buy` as input and outputs a vector of new `htm_prc` with all runs starting with `buy == 1` of length 3.

```r
htm <- data.frame (Date  = c("Jan 2001", "Feb 2001", "Mar 2001", "Apr 2001", "May 2001", "Jun 2001", "Jul 2001", "Aug 2001", "Aug 2001"),
                   prc = c(34, 35, 38, 24, 22, 18, 30, 32, 38),
                   buy = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0),
                   portfolio = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0),
                   htm_prc = c(34, 34, 34, 24, NA, 18, 18, 32, NA))


hold_runs <- function(x, buy) {
  n <- length(x)
  inx <- which((buy == 1) & c(TRUE, diff(buy) == 1L))
  if(length(inx)) {
    i_last_run <- pmin(n, inx + 2L)
    for(i in seq_along(inx)) {
      x[ inx[i]:i_last_run[i] ] <- x[ inx[i] ]
    }
  }
  x
}

htm$new_htm_prc <- with(htm, hold_runs(htm_prc, buy))
htm
#>       Date prc buy portfolio htm_prc new_htm_prc
#> 1 Jan 2001  34   1         1      34          34
#> 2 Feb 2001  35   1         1      34          34
#> 3 Mar 2001  38   0         1      34          34
#> 4 Apr 2001  24   0         1      24          24
#> 5 May 2001  22   0         0      NA          NA
#> 6 Jun 2001  18   1         1      18          18
#> 7 Jul 2001  30   0         1      18          18
#> 8 Aug 2001  32   0         1      32          18
#> 9 Aug 2001  38   0         0      NA          NA
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-16 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much! Just one question: I would like the new column to look like "htm_prc". So instead  of the last 34, it would be a 24. So htm_prc, is as i would like the result to look like. Is that an easy modification of your function? Thank you !!

Comment: Shouldn't Aug 2001 `htm_prc` be 18 too?

Comment: @FreddyMüller Done, see now.